# iOS Promise Kit and Await Kit in swift

Tags: ios, swift, promise, async-await, promisekit

I am trying to use async await / Promise. I have a function like this:

```
extension DemoWebCrypto {

    class func runWEC(password: String, encrypted: Data) {
        let crypto = WebCrypto()
        crypto.decrypt(data: encrypted,
                       password: password,
                       callback: { (decrypted: Data?, error: Error?) in
              print("Error:", error)
              let text = String(data: decrypted!, encoding: .utf8)
              print("decrypt:", text)
        })
    }

}
```

Normally we call this function like this

```
let enc1 = "......."
let password = "....."
let data1 = Data(base64Encoded: enc1, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
DemoWebCrypto.runEC(password: password, encrypted: data1) {

}
```

So I want to remove this trailing closure implementation via **[AwaitKit](https://github.com/yannickl/AwaitKit)** i.e. want to replace via async await way.

How I do that so I can get the string? Something like

```
let result = try await(DemoWebCrypto.runWEC(password: ..., encrypted: ...))
print(result) // the decrypt text
```

Answer (score 0):

AwaitKit works in conjunction with PromiseKit to get the result you're waiting for. You'll need to change your function `runWEC` to return a `Promise` of a `String` like so:

```
class func runWEC(password: String, encrypted: Data) -> Promise<String> {
    return Promise { seal in
        let crypto = WebCrypto()
        crypto.decrypt(data: encrypted,
                       password: password,
                       callback: { (decrypted: Data?, error: Error?) in
              if let error = error {
                  seal.reject(error)
              }

              let text = String(data: decrypted!, encoding: .utf8)
              seal.fulfill(text)
        })
    }
}
```

Then you'll be able to use the `try? await()` function.

```
if let result = try? await(DemoWebCrypto.runWEC(password: ..., encrypted: ...)) {
    print(result) // the decrypt text
}
```